# How to enable a submit button after a php script ends?

Tags: php, ajax

How do I enable a sumbit button after a php script ends?

For example:

In my index.php page I have a submit button who is disabled by default, and after a php script (script.php) ends I want to enabled it.

The idea sp far is put a boolean variable in the end of script.php, so when it ends I set it to true. But how do I continue check if the boolean variable changed to true? I'm guessing that we use ajax...I already know how to disable the html button.

Comment: Are you calling via ajax script.php and waiting for it to finish?

Comment: I don't understand the logic here. Php is a server side language. It sends the response after parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of script execution create a file and at the front-end, continously check if that file exists. This is how you do this in jQuery.

```
function ft(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false 
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "enable.txt", 
        method: 'get',
        error: function(){return true;}, //if 404 error continue the request
        success: function(data){
            $("#your_element").attr("disabled","false");
            window.clearInterval(timeOutId); //Stop the request of getting the file,
        }
    });               
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    timeOutId = window.setInterval("ft()", 10000); //repeat after 10 seconds.
});
```